# Why is objc_super.receiver unavailable in ARC?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, superclass, objective-c-runtime

How do I fix the compiler error `'receiver' is unavailable: this system field has retaining ownership` in line 3 below?

```
UIKIT_STATIC_INLINE void sample_drawRect(id self, SEL _cmd, CGRect rect) {
    struct objc_super super;
    super.receiver = self;
    super.super_class = class_getSuperclass([self class]);
    objc_msgSendSuper(&super, @selector(drawRect:));
}
```

Comment: What happens if you use malloc and a pointer to a struct objc_super?

Answer (score 2):

With ARC, C-Structs can't store pointers to Objective-C objects.

Have you tried a bridging cast, like this?

```
super.receiver = (__bridge void*)self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use objective-c++ instead of objective-c (.mm file).